# How to setup "trigger method" for when a float variable reaches a certain value

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation

I've been working with a BLE-042 Cypress module that sends voltage data (0V-3.3V) in `Float32` form, which I capture via delegate methods in my iOS application, and print to my screen (via a rectangle with the value on it, and a dynamic line graph using Core Plot 2.2).  For this particular project, if the `Float32` voltage > 2.0V, then I want to make that rectangle with the value blink to issue a warning.

The Core Plot graph has to run on the main thread, and blinking cannot interrupt the flow of capturing data from the BLE delegate methods.  I want the rectangle to blink without making the data out-out-sync with reality.

Here's the delegate method for capturing my data:

```
- (void)getTransducerData:(CBCharacteristic*)characteristic error:(NSError*)error {
    NSData* data = [characteristic value];
    const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
    uint32_t v0 = (uint32_t)reportData[0];
    uint32_t v1 = (uint32_t)reportData[1] << 8;
    uint32_t v2 = (uint32_t)reportData[2] << 16;
    uint32_t v3 = (uint32_t)reportData[3] << 24;

    uint32_t voltage = v0 | v1 | v2 | v3;

    if ((characteristic.value) || !error) {
        self.transducerValue = voltage;
        _real = voltage/1000000.0;
        self.transducerPosition.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.4lf V", _real];
    }
}
```

I was thinking of applying an `if` condition right after `_real` has the new value:

```
_real = voltage/1000000.0;
if (_real > 2.0) {
    // start blinking rectangle
}
```

The problem is I don't want that `if` statement in there at all.  I just want the `// start blinking rectangle` part to start based on an event condition....not because any `if` statement is telling it to blink.

Any suggestions as to how I can get this done?  If you think that the animation of blinking will not be "a heavy load" to be applied within an `if` statement condition, then let me know.  Also, as a side note, I have an ADC sampling at 70000 samples/sec, and the `getTransducerData:error:` is really pumping out values.

I'm using Objective-C with Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: If you were accessing `_real` as a _property_, e.g. `self.real`, then you would be passing through a setter accessor which could observe the incoming value and respond as desired.

Comment: I thought about that but isn't that same idea as observing in the way I mentioned?  If I were to write an observation condition in the setter method, would it not still be executed at the speed in which the BLE characteristic is captured (whether the condition be true or not)? Unless, again, this process is not costly at all in terms of UI "experience".

Comment: So you're saying that, while your program is chugging along at high speed, you want a sleepy little man to wake up inside your program from time to time and look to see whether `_real` is currently above a certain value? So why not use an NSTimer? Or a CADisplayLink? This will work as long as you are not running in a tight loop (i.e. as long as you are not blocking the main thread continually). It sounds like you should be gathering your data on a background thread anyway; otherwise you can't update the interface without "interrupting the flow".

Comment: Now might be a great time for me to learn background threading (or, threading in general).  I have an `NSTimer` that triggers the display of plot points, however, if I incorporated one to capture `_real`, I'm afraid it might miss the exact point at which `_real > 2.0`.  Imagine the idea behind an interrupt system (as an ISR loop), but instead of interrupting the flow, it creates like a "side action" to run alongside the main flow.  Is this territory belonging to background threading?  Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: "I'm afraid it might miss the exact point at which `_real > 2.0`" Ah. But now you are blowing hot and cold in the same breath. You want a sleepy little man who doesn't interrupt, but you want to know exactly when the overflow happened. So maybe you will need to do what I said the first time. But instead of redrawing right then, just record the fact that we went over `2.0` along with a timestamp. Now when your display routine comes along it has the information it needs. In other words, separate recording of data (fast) from analysis / display (slow, intermittent).

Comment: Ah-ha, I see what you're saying...I'll set up the setter accessor to say whether or not the voltage went over 2.0.  How would I set up the method that controls the blinking so that it's not being every single time the setter accessor notices the > 2.0 condition?  Once the setter notices 2.0, I want a `blinkStart` method to begin...but only get called once.....then when accessor notices < 2.0, triggers a `blinkEnd` method only once.  Repeating this process for the lifetime of the view controller.

Comment: Let's say I have two variables I want to check as part of an `if` statement in my `self.real` setter accessor: one to control the point at which a `blinkStart` method should be called (in this case, `self.real` > 2.0V), and one to determine if the `blinkStart` method was ever called to begin with (I'll call this `self.blinkOn`).  When `self.real > 2.0`, `blinkStart` gets called.  Then a fast `NSTimer` is enabled to keep the process of blinking going (at which point `self.blinkOn = 1`.  The process will repeat, this time though, the `if (self.real > 2.0 && self.blinkOn != 0)` in the accessor

Comment: ....won't trigger, which will not create another `NSTimer` instance.  Then, `if (self.real < 2.0 && self.blinkOn == 1)` evaluates to True, the `blinkEnd` method will be called...stopping the timer.    Would this be a non-costly way of coding this scenario?

Comment: Thanks, writing a setter accessor along with an `NSTimer` works well!  Also, check out this app I just made called Twinstones if you have time (good for train rides, passenger-seat car rides, bathroom diversions, etc.)